# Spring Boot JSON serialization with parent table

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-boot, jackson

Good morning, I am trying to receive from spring boot with a ajax call a JSON with a series of fields containing daughter tables and also father.

I already had the problem of infinite recursion and such and fixed it with @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference. What is happening now? I need to at least get to the data in the parent table to get a value but this one, when we get to the answer in Ajax it doesn't appear.

How could I do so that I could get to that data without falling into infinite recursion?

These would be the tables, I remove the fields so that it is not very long.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="actividad_servicio")
public class Actividad_Servicio implements Serializable {

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_actividad_servicio_tipo_actividad_servicio_id"), name="tipo_actividad_servicio_id", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "int")
    private Tipo_Actividad_Servicio tipo_actividad_servicio;
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_actividad_servicio_empleado_id"), name="empleado_id",columnDefinition = "int")
    private Empleado empleado;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "actividad_servicio", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Actividad_Servicio_Alumno> actividad_servicio_alumno = new HashSet<Actividad_Servicio_Alumno>();
    
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "actividad_servicio", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Horario_Actividad_Servicio horario_actividad_servicio = new Horario_Actividad_Servicio();

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "actividad_servicio", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Factura> factura = new HashSet<Factura>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name="horario_actividad_servicio")
public class Horario_Actividad_Servicio implements Serializable {

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_horario_actividad_servicio_actividad_servicio_id"), name="actividad_servicio_id", referencedColumnName = "id", columnDefinition = "int")
    private Actividad_Servicio actividad_servicio;

}

@Entity
@Table(name="tipo_actividad_servicio")
public class Tipo_Actividad_Servicio implements Serializable {

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tipo_actividad_servicio", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Actividad_Servicio> actividad_servicio = new HashSet<Actividad_Servicio>();

}
```

Before returning the response back to Ajax, I look at the content of the service_activity object and it shows me the service_activity_type and its attributes.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/actividades/rest")
public class ActividadRestController {

    @Autowired
    private Actividad_ServicioService actividad_servicioService;

    @GetMapping
    public Response findOne(@RequestParam int id, Model model) {

        Response response = new Response();

        try {
            Actividad_Servicio actividad_servicio = actividad_servicioService.findById(id);

            response = new Response("Done", actividad_servicio);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            response = new Response("Error", Constants.Error);
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return response;

    }

}
```

But when it comes back to Ajax I have inspected the content what I get is this:

```
Success:  - {…}
​            - data: {…}
​​              +  actividad_servicio_alumno: Array []
​​              +  factura: Array []
​​              +  horario_actividad_servicio: Object { id: 10, l: null, hora_inicio_l: "", …}
​​                 <prototype>: Object { … }
​              status: "Done"
​              <prototype>: Object { … }
```

But the service_activity_type does not appear in order to obtain the value of some field. I know that this collides with the issue of infinite recursion but I suppose that there is something there is an annotation that happens to me that I have left to put so that I can obtain those parent values.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use Entity class directly as response, it will create many problem when you want to ignore partially.

Create DTO class for the response to serialize only those fields you want to send. Map entity data in response using any model mapping tools like Modelmapper or MapStruct.